# How to check if a column only contains certain letters

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe and I want to check one column that only contains letter A for example.

The column contains a lot of letters. It looks like:

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAABBBBBDBBSBSBB

I want to check if this column only contains letter A, or both letter A or B, but nothing else.

Do you know which function I shall use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: I have considered four samples of letters. We can use `rlike` function in spark. I have used regex of `[^AB]`. This will return `true` to the column values having letters other than `A` or `B` and `False` will be displayed to the values having  A or B or both AB. we can filter out `False` and that will be your answer.

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F

    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName('SO')\
        .getOrCreate()

    li = [[("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBDBBSBSBB")], [("AAAAAAAAA")],[("BBBBBBBB")], [("AAAAAABBBBBBBB")]]

    df = spark.createDataFrame(li, ["letter"])

    df.show(truncate=False)

    # 
    # +--------------------------------+
    # |letter                          |
    # +--------------------------------+
    # |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBDBBSBSBB|
    # |AAAAAAAAA                       |
    # |BBBBBBBB                        |
    # |AAAAAABBBBBBBB                  |
    # +--------------------------------+

    df1 = df.withColumn("contains_A_or_B", F.col('letter').rlike("[^AB]"))

    df.show(truncate=False)

      +--------------------------------+---------------+
    # |letter                          |contains_A_or_B|
    # +--------------------------------+---------------+
    # |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBDBBSBSBB|true           |
    # |AAAAAAAAA                       |false          |
    # |BBBBBBBB                        |false          |
    # |AAAAAABBBBBBBB                  |false          |
    # +--------------------------------+---------------+
    df1.filter(F.col('contains_A_or_B')==False).select("letter").show()


    # +--------------+
    # |        letter|
    # +--------------+
    # |     AAAAAAAAA|
    # |      BBBBBBBB|
    # |AAAAAABBBBBBBB|
    # +--------------+
```

Comment: Hi @kites, can you please help me understand what is the use of `^` in the `rlike` statement?

Comment: @SDS, it is used to indicate begins with.

Comment: Thanks @kites. However, I have seen many cases - if the letter does not `begins with` also the condition works. any thoughts on the same. It works like `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

Use rlike.
Example from the official documentation:

```
df.filter(df.name.rlike('ice$')).collect()
[Row(age=2, name='Alice')]
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=regex#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike